# can not reduce zurb foundation form input width

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation

I am new to Zurb Foundation, and using it in my React 16 project. And just not been able to reduce the width of the **form-input and button** within a component named **CountdownForm.jsx**.  These two elements (**form-input and button**) are taking the entire width of the page. And I would like to keep them centred and 30% width.

Would highly appreciate any help.

I have the following code in my **Main.jsx**

```
var Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation/>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="column small-centered medium-6 large-4">
          {props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

module.exports = Main;
```

And then in my child component named **CountdownForm.jsx** I have written as below

```
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <form ref="form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="countdown-form">
          <input type="text" ref="seconds" placeholder="Enter time in seconds"/>
          <button className="button expanded">Start</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = CountdownForm;
```

I also have a file named _countdownForm.scss for styling the form and I have included the below in this file

```
.countdown-form {
  width: 30%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

the width of the form-input was supposed to be set by foundation's grid system which I am defining in my Main.jsx (the below part)

```
<div className="row">
        <div className="column small-centered medium-6 large-4">
          {props.children}
</div>
```

I am using "foundation-sites": "6.4.4-rc1" and "react": "^16.0.0". The github of the project https://github.com/rohan-paul/ReactCountdownTimer

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind.. Got it resolved..

I had to adjust the Countdown.jsx component to fix this, not the Main.jsx”  ( and .coutdownForm CSS class defined in _countdownForm.scss had no impact at this point of the app in resolving this issue, as the centering of form-input was handled in the render section of the component Countdown.jsx )

So, I just changed Countdown.jsx as follows:

FROM

```
else {
        return <CountdownForm onSetCountdown={this.handleSetCountdown}/>;
      }
```

TO

```
else {        
        return (
          <div className="grid-container">
            <div className="cell small-centered medium-6 large-4">
              <CountdownForm onSetCountdown={this.handleSetCountdown} />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
```

https://github.com/rohan-paul/ReactCountdownTimer/blob/master/app/components/Countdown.jsx